# fbprophet yearly seasonality volatility

Tags: python, regression, finance, facebook-prophet

I am new to using fbprophet and have a question about using the predict function.

As an example, I am using fbprophet to extrapolate Apples revenue for the next 5 years. Below is the code using the default settings.

```
m = Prophet()

m.fit(data)

future = m.make_future_dataframe(periods=5*365)

forecast = m.predict(future)

m.plot(forecast)
m.plot_components(forecast)

plt.show()
```

The results:
[image]

[image]

If I choose to remove the "yearly seasonality", I get a linear regression that fits much better.

[image]

My question is why do the predicted yhat results blow up so much when yearly seasonality is included. As shown, turning the option off produces a linear regression model but I'm unsure whether this model is most suitable for the data. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using monthly data and not daily data.
So instead of using "periods=5*365" you can change the freq to monthly.

Example:

```
future_pd = m.make_future_dataframe(periods = 12 * 5,
                                    freq='MS',
                                    include_history=True)
```